# Github ERROUploadArtifac -Next.js Project

Tags: github, next.js, github-pages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98F4I.png)

I'm having headache to publish my Next.js projects. Works fine on Localhost
Something to do with Artifact Files. I cant figure out the mistake.

jobs:

## Build job

build:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: Checkout
uses: actions/checkout@v4
- name: Detect package manager
id: detect-package-manager
run: |
if [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/yarn.lock" ]; then
echo "manager=yarn" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "command=install" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "runner=yarn" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
exit 0
elif [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/package.json" ]; then
echo "manager=npm" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "command=ci" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "runner=npx --no-install" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
exit 0
else
echo "Unable to determine package manager"
exit 1
fi
- name: Setup Node
uses: actions/setup-node@v4
with:
node-version: "20"
cache: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }}
- name: Setup Pages
uses: actions/configure-pages@v4
with:
# Automatically inject basePath in your Next.js configuration file and disable
# server side image optimization (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized).
#
# You may remove this line if you want to manage the configuration yourself.
static_site_generator: next
- name: Restore cache
uses: actions/cache@v4
with:
path: |
.next/cache
# Generate a new cache whenever packages or source files change.
key: ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json', '**/yarn.lock') }}-${{ hashFiles('**.[jt]s', '**.[jt]sx') }}
# If source files changed but packages didn't, rebuild from a prior cache.
restore-keys: |
${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json', '**/yarn.lock') }}-
- name: Install dependencies
run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }} ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.command }}
- name: Build and Static HTML export with Next.js
run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.runner }} next build
- name: Upload artifact
uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
with:
path: ./out

I attempt to research and ask GPT, but I am unable to resolve it.